# Writing a list to a file with Python, with newlines

Tags: python, file, list, file-io, newline

How do I write a list to a file? `writelines()` doesn't insert newline characters, so I need to do:

```
f.writelines([f"{line}\n" for line in lines])
```

Comment: do note that `writelines` doesn't add newlines because it mirrors `readlines`, which also doesn't remove them.

Comment: its between json vs pickle. read all about it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745500/how-to-save-a-list-to-a-file-and-read-it-as-a-list-type

Answer (score 1305, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
with open('your_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(f"{line}\n")
```

For Python <3.6:

```
with open('your_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write("%s\n" % line)
```

For Python 2, one may also use:

```
with open('your_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        print >> f, line
```

If you're keen on a single function call, at least remove the square brackets `[]`, so that the strings to be printed get made one at a time (a genexp rather than a listcomp) -- no reason to take up all the memory required to materialize the whole list of strings.

Answer (score 501):

What are you going to do with the file? Does this file exist for humans, or other programs with clear interoperability requirements?

If you are just trying to serialize a list to disk for later use by the same python app, you should be [pickleing](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) the list.

```
import pickle

with open('outfile', 'wb') as fp:
    pickle.dump(itemlist, fp)
```

To read it back:

```
with open ('outfile', 'rb') as fp:
    itemlist = pickle.load(fp)
```

Comment: "Warning: The pickle module is not secure. Only unpickle data you trust.

It is possible to construct malicious pickle data which will execute arbitrary code during unpickling. Never unpickle data that could have come from an untrusted source, or that could have been tampered with." -- From the same manual page linked on the answer.

Comment: Pickle has the problem that it can change whenever you upgrade python. What you pickle in python 3.n you might not be able to unpickle in python 3.(n+1). This bit me once.

Answer (score 441):

Simpler is:

```python
with open("outfile", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write("\n".join(itemlist))
```

To ensure that all items in the item list are strings, use a generator expression:

```python
with open("outfile", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write("\n".join(str(item) for item in itemlist))
```

Remember that `itemlist` takes up memory, so take care about the memory consumption.

Comment: No trailing newline, uses 2x space compared to the loop.

Answer (score 106):

Using **Python 3** and **Python 2.6+** syntax:

```
with open(filepath, 'w') as file_handler:
    for item in the_list:
        file_handler.write("{}\n".format(item))
```

This is platform-independent. It also terminates the final line with a newline character, which is a [UNIX best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline).

Starting with Python 3.6, `"{}\n".format(item)` can be replaced with an f-string: `f"{item}\n"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/899176/9962007

Answer (score 97):

Yet another way.  Serialize to json using [simplejson](http://code.google.com/p/simplejson/) (included as [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) in python 2.6):

```
>>> import simplejson
>>> f = open('output.txt', 'w')
>>> simplejson.dump([1,2,3,4], f)
>>> f.close()
```

If you examine output.txt:

> [1, 2, 3, 4]

This is useful because the syntax is pythonic, it's human readable, and it can be read by other programs in other languages.

Answer (score 44):

I thought it would be interesting to explore the benefits of using a genexp, so here's my take.

The example in the question uses square brackets to create a temporary list, and so is equivalent to:

```
file.writelines( list( "%s\n" % item for item in list ) )
```

Which needlessly constructs a temporary list of all the lines that will be written out, this may consume significant amounts of memory depending on the size of your list and how verbose the output of `str(item)` is.

Drop the square brackets (equivalent to removing the wrapping `list()` call above) will instead pass a temporary [generator](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/) to `file.writelines()`:

```
file.writelines( "%s\n" % item for item in list )
```

This generator will create newline-terminated representation of your `item` objects on-demand (i.e. as they are written out). This is nice for a couple of reasons:

- Memory overheads are small, even for very large lists
- If `str(item)` is slow there's visible progress in the file as each item is processed

---

This avoids memory issues, such as:

```
In [1]: import os

In [2]: f = file(os.devnull, "w")

In [3]: %timeit f.writelines( "%s\n" % item for item in xrange(2**20) )
1 loops, best of 3: 385 ms per loop

In [4]: %timeit f.writelines( ["%s\n" % item for item in xrange(2**20)] )
ERROR: Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
MemoryError
```

(I triggered this error by limiting Python's max. virtual memory to ~100MB with `ulimit -v 102400`).

Putting memory usage to one side, this method isn't actually any faster than the original:

```
In [4]: %timeit f.writelines( "%s\n" % item for item in xrange(2**20) )
1 loops, best of 3: 370 ms per loop

In [5]: %timeit f.writelines( ["%s\n" % item for item in xrange(2**20)] )
1 loops, best of 3: 360 ms per loop
```

(Python 2.6.2 on Linux)

Answer (score 31):

Because i'm lazy....

```
import json
a = [1,2,3]
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(a))

#Now read the file back into a Python list object
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    a = json.loads(f.read())
```

Answer (score 25):

In Python 3 you can use `print` and `*` for argument unpacking:

```
with open("fout.txt", "w") as fout:
    print(*my_list, sep="\n", file=fout)
```

Answer (score 21):

Serialize list into text file with comma sepparated value

```
mylist = dir()
with open('filename.txt','w') as f:
    f.write( ','.join( mylist ) )
```

Answer (score 18):

Simply:

```
with open("text.txt", 'w') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(yourList))
```

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/899149/9962007

Answer (score 17):

## In General

Following is the syntax for **writelines()** method

```
fileObject.writelines( sequence )
```

## Example

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Open a file
fo = open("foo.txt", "rw+")
seq = ["This is 6th line\n", "This is 7th line"]

# Write sequence of lines at the end of the file.
line = fo.writelines( seq )

# Close opend file
fo.close()
```

## Reference

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_writelines.htm

Answer (score 14):

```
file.write('\n'.join(list))
```

Answer (score 14):

Using `numpy.savetxt` is also an option:

```py
import numpy as np

np.savetxt('list.txt', list, delimiter="\n", fmt="%s")
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the print function if you're on python3 as follows.

```
f = open("myfile.txt","wb")
print(mylist, file=f)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
with open ("test.txt","w")as fp:
   for line in list12:
       fp.write(line+"\n")
```

Answer (score 5):

I recently found Path to be useful. Helps me get around having to `with open('file') as f` and then writing to the file. Hope this becomes useful to someone :).

```py
from pathlib import Path
import json
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
# write
Path("file.json").write_text(json.dumps(a))
# read
json.loads(Path("file.json").read_text())
```

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you try

```
file.write(str(list))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also go through following:

Example:

```
my_list=[1,2,3,4,5,"abc","def"]
with open('your_file.txt', 'w') as file:
    for item in my_list:
        file.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Output:

In `your_file.txt` items are saved like:

```
1

2

3

4

5

abc

def
```

Your script also saves as above.

Otherwise, you can use pickle

```
import pickle
my_list=[1,2,3,4,5,"abc","def"]
#to write
with open('your_file.txt', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(my_list, file)
#to read
with open ('your_file.txt', 'rb') as file:
    Outlist = pickle.load(file)
print(Outlist)
```

Output:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'abc', 'def']

It save dump the list same as a list when we load it we able to read.

Also by `simplejson` possible same as above output

```
import simplejson as sj
my_list=[1,2,3,4,5,"abc","def"]
#To write
with open('your_file.txt', 'w') as file:
    sj.dump(my_list, file)

#To save
with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as file:
    mlist=sj.load(file)
print(mlist)
```

Answer (score 2):

This logic will first convert the items in list to `string(str)`. Sometimes the list contains a tuple like

```
alist = [(i12,tiger), 
(113,lion)]
```

This logic will write to file each tuple in a new line. We can later use `eval` while loading each tuple when reading the file:

```
outfile = open('outfile.txt', 'w') # open a file in write mode
for item in list_to_persistence:    # iterate over the list items
   outfile.write(str(item) + '\n') # write to the file
outfile.close()   # close the file
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of iterating and adding newline:

```
for item in items:
    filewriter.write(f"{item}" + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Python3** You Can use this loop

```
with open('your_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in list:
        f.print("", item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting stdout to a file might also be useful for this purpose:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
  with redirect_stdout(f):
     for i in range(mylst.size):
        print(mylst[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest this solution .

```
with open('your_file.txt', 'w') as f:        
    list(map(lambda item : f.write("%s\n" % item),my_list))
```

Answer (score -1):

Let avg be the list, then:

```
In [29]: a = n.array((avg))
In [31]: a.tofile('avgpoints.dat',sep='\n',dtype = '%f')
```

You can use `%e` or `%s` depending on your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

i think you are looking for an answer like this.

```
f = open('output.txt','w')
list = [3, 15.2123, 118.3432, 98.2276, 118.0043]
f.write('a= {:>3d}, b= {:>8.4f}, c= {:>8.4f}, d= {:>8.4f}, e= 
{:>8.4f}\n'.format(*list))
f.close()
```

Comment: what is this doing?

Answer (score -4):

```
poem = '''\
Programming is fun
When the work is done
if you wanna make your work also fun:
use Python!
'''
f = open('poem.txt', 'w') # open for 'w'riting
f.write(poem) # write text to file
f.close() # close the file
```

How It Works:
First, open a ﬁle by using the built-in open function and specifying the name of
the ﬁle and the mode in which we want to open the ﬁle. The mode can be a
read mode (’r’), write mode (’w’) or append mode (’a’). We can also specify
whether we are reading, writing, or appending in text mode (’t’) or binary
mode (’b’). There are actually many more modes available and help(open)
will give you more details about them. By default, open() considers the ﬁle to
be a ’t’ext ﬁle and opens it in ’r’ead mode.
In our example, we ﬁrst open the ﬁle in write text mode and use the write
method of the ﬁle object to write to the ﬁle and then we ﬁnally close the ﬁle.

**The above example is from the book "A Byte of Python" by Swaroop C H.**
[swaroopch.com](http://swaroopch.com/)

Comment: This writes a string to a file, not a list (of strings) as the OP asks

Comment: You need to relate answers to OPs rather more directly than just bolstering your answer number by pasting from other site.