# Write multiple variables to a file

Tags: python

I want to write two variable to a file using Python.

Based on what is stated [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/python-write-a-list-to-a-file) I wrote:

```
f.open('out','w')
f.write("%s %s\n" %str(int("0xFF",16)) %str(int("0xAA",16))
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "process-python", line 8, in <module>
    o.write("%s %s\n" %str(int("0xFF", 16))  %str(int("0xAA", 16)))
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Comment: is this even syntactically correct? I would think it would have to be `"%s %s\n" % (str(int("0xFF", 16)), str(int("0xAA", 16)))`

Comment: Why are you using `str(int())`, anyway? `"%i %i\n" % (int("0xFF", 16), int("0xAA",16))` would work just as well and, in my opinion, is a bit clearer. Also, if only hexadecimal strings are guaranteed to begin with `0x` then you can use `int(string, 0)`, as that will automatically convert properly-prefixed octal strings and handle decimal strings correctly as well. If all your strings are hex and might not be preceded by `0x` then using `int(string, 16)` is probably how you need to go, though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are not passing enough values to `%`, you have two specifiers in your format string so it expects a tuple of length 2.  Try this:

```
f.write("%s %s\n" % (int("0xFF" ,16), int("0xAA", 16)))
```

Comment: @mahmood yes I have, what problem are you having?

Comment: ok thanks. I had problems with opened and closed brackets. Now it is ok

Answer (score 3):

Better use [`format`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) this way:

```
'{0} {1}\n'.format(int("0xFF",16), int("0xAA",16))
```

Also there is no need to wrap `int` with `str`.

Comment: yeah format is nice providing he is using python2.7 or greater

Comment: `format` is available in 2.6, although you must explicitly number the replacement fields (i.e., `'{0} {1}\n'.format(...)`).

Answer (score 2):

The % operator takes an object or tuple. So the correct way to write this is:

```
f.write("%s %s\n" % (int("0xFF", 16), int("0xAA",16)))
```

There are also many other ways how to format a string, documentation is your friend http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your opening the file is wrong `f.open('out', 'w')` should probably be:

```
f = open('out', 'w')
```

Then, for such simple formatting, you can use `print`, for Python 2.x, as:

```
print >> f, int('0xff', 16), int('0xaa', 16)
```

Or, for Python 3.x:

```
print(int('0xff', 16), int('0xaa', 16), file=f)
```

Otherwise, use `.format`:

```
f.write('{} {}'.format(int('0xff', 16), int('0xaa', 16)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply a tuple:

```
f.open('out','w')
f.write("%d %d\n" % (int("0xFF",16), int("0xAA",16)))
```

Answer (score -1):

This should probably be written as:

```
f.write("255 170\n")
```

Comment: Those are constant in the example. In reality they are variables.