# how to update global variable in python

Tags: python, list, function, global

In python, i have a function that returns a list of the latest links(to folders) on a website. I also have another function that downloads the latest files from those folders. I plan to run this script everyday. I have a global list with the folder links that the download function accesses everytime it runs for the latest folders. I want to update that global list every five days and keep it static for the next 5 days i run the code until it updates again.

Its sort of like this:

```
list = ["link1", "link2",...]

def update():
  #code to update list
  return list

def download(list):
  #code to download from links
```

So I want the update function to run every 5 days(I know how to do that) and the download function to run everyday. So how can i keep the list returned from update() static as the global list until it is updated again?

EDIT:
Let me try to clarify:

I run this on a monday:

```
list = ["link1", "link2"]

def update():
  #code to update list
  return list #--> list = ["link1", "link2", "link3"]

def download(list):
  #code to download from links
```

this worked fine, list was updated and used in download().

I run this on a Tuesday:

```
list = ["link1", "link2"]
#update() won't run today, only runs every 5 days
def update():
  #code to update list
  return list #--> list = ["link1", "link2", "link3"]

def download(list):
  #code to download from links
```

I restarted my code, but now list doesnt have link3 from monday. How do i keep link3 in the list for the next 5 days until i update list again?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `global` statement. But there's no need of `global` for mutable objects, if you're modifying them in-place.

You can use modules like [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) to store your list in a file. You can load the list when you want to use it and store it back after doing your modifications.

```
lis = ["link1", "link2",...]

def update():
  global lis
  #do something
  return lis
```

Pickle example:

```
import pickle
def update():
  lis = pickle.load( open( "lis.pkl", "rb" ) ) # Load the list
  #do something with lis                     #modify it 
  pickle.dump( lis, open( "lis.pkl", "wb" ) )  #save it again
```

For better performance you can also use the [cPickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-cPickle) module.

[More examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle-example)

Comment: yes, but this will update list for the time the script is running. The script will close in a few minutes. WHen i run it the next day, i want it to be the same list that the update returned the previous day. i hope i am clear enough. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @VaibhavAggarwal I guess you need to use modules like pickle to store your list object, see my updated answer.

Comment: @VaibhavAggarwal I've added a pickle related example.

Comment: @VaibhavAggarwal Go for [cPickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-cPickle) then, it's can be up to 1000 times faster than `pickle`.

Answer (score 2):

Normal declaration of the variable will make it local.
Use global keyword to make it render as global.

Just write the list to a file and access it read it from there later.

If you don't want to self run the code you can use cron-job to do it for you.

```
def read_file(filename):
    f = open(filename).read().split()
    lis = []
    for i in f:
            lis.append(i)
    return lis 

def write_file(filename,lis):
        f = open(filename,"w")
        for i in lis:
                f.write(str(i)+'\n')
```

Comment: Thanks, but if you don't mind, could you write an example code for accessing the file, writing to it and saving it?

Answer (score 1):

As long as it is declared in the main program and not within the scope of the function you should be fine to manipulate your `list` variable from there (your comment) just fine.  If you want initialize it as global to from within the scope of a method you can use the `global` keyword to broaden the scope to the whole program

```
list = ["link1", "link2",...]

def update():
  list.append("link25")
  return list
```

will append link25 to the global list as you wanted

If you want your list to be persistent between runs, you can save it to a file and load it from that file each time or save it to a database and load it from a database if you need it to work on multiple machines

you can write the items in your list to a file by doing this

```
for item in thelist:
    thefile.write("%s\n" % item)
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/python-write-a-list-to-a-file)