# How can use this variable outside the function?

Tags: function, python-3.x, variables, scope

```
Three_Series = ["3S BLACK STOCK RIMS.png"]

def SelectedCarFunction(event=None):
    Model = Var2.get()
    Colour = Var3.get()
    Wheels = Var4.get()
```

The variables `Model`, `Colour` and `Wheels` are retrieved perfectly as they should be

```
if Model == "3 Series" and Colour == "Black" and Wheels == "Stock":
    VarSC = Three_Series[0]
    print(VarSC)
```

I put `print(VarSC)` here to test to see if it would print `"3S BLACK STOCK RIMS.png"` and it did

```
   return VarSC

VarSC = StringVar()

DisplayFrame.grid_propagate(False)

print(VarSC)
```

However, now when I `print(VarSC)` to see if it prints the same value as be before it doesn't, instead it prints out `PY_VAR9`

```
CarImage = PhotoImage(file=VarSC)
```

Here I want to assign the file to `VarSC`, i.e I want VarSC to equal `"3S BLACK STOCK RIMS.png"` but it doesn't

```
CarImageLabel = Label(DisplayFrame, image=CarImage)
CarImageLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Here's the entire code:

```
Three_Series = ["3S BLACK STOCK RIMS.png"]

def SelectedCarFunction(event=None):
    Model = Var2.get()
    Colour = Var3.get()
    Wheels = Var4.get()

    if Model == "3 Series" and Colour == "Black" and Wheels == "Stock":
    VarSC = Three_Series[0]
    print(VarSC)
    return VarSC

VarSC = StringVar()

DisplayFrame.grid_propagate(False)

print(VarSC)
CarImage = PhotoImage(file=VarSC)
CarImageLabel = Label(DisplayFrame, image=CarImage)
CarImageLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please post the entire code in a single block.  It is impossible to see what is actually happening.

Comment: Done, posted the entire code underneath @BrianPendleton

Comment: If you want `VarSC` to be the result of `SelectedCarFunction`, then you need to say `VarSc = SelectedCarFunction()`?  I'm still confused because you have a lot of missing context and code still.  What is `root`?

Comment: Root is used as this is GUI program on tkinter. The value of VarSC in the function is "3S BLACK STOCK RIMS.png" but when I try to use VarSC outside the function it gives me PY_VAR9. How can I get the same value of VarSC outside the function?? @BrianPendleton

Comment: I'd have a look at other answer for updating global variables inside functions.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17307521/4080476

Comment: I had a look and tried using global VarSC in the function but that did not solve the problem @BrianPendleton

Comment: @Brian Oakley HELP?!?

Comment: Nothing in the code you've shown ever calls your `SelectedCarFunction`, so its return value cannot possibly be used anywhere. If it's being called from somewhere you haven't shown, well, we can't debug code we can't see. Please show enough of your code that we can actually run it and see the same problem you're describing.