# How do I update a global variable in python?

Tags: python

I am declaring global variable in sample1.py like this and updating

```
sample1.py
var = 0
def foo():
    global var
    var = 10
```

In sample2.py I am importing this global variable

```
sample2.py
from sample1 import var

def foo1():
    print var
```

but, still it is printing "0" instead of "10". If print it in sample1.py it is printing "10".

What went wrong?

Comment: like berthos said you are only importing `var` from `sample1.py` not the setting it to 10

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to update global variable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307474/how-to-update-global-variable-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

What is wrong is that the function from sample1.py is never called, ergo you variable is never initialized with 10

Correct way

Sample1.py

```
var = 0
def Function1:
   var = 10
```

Sample2.py

```
import Sample1
Sample1.Function1()
print(Function1.var)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't called the function `foo()` in `sample2.py`, right now only declared the variable with `0` when you call the function `foo()`, then only it will update.

update `sample2.py` like this,

```
from sample1 import var,foo
foo()

def foo1():
    print var
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, even though you have already called function `foo`, it won't work. Because when you use `from sample1 import var`, you just get a copy of `sample1.var`, but not really get the pointer of it. So it won't be updated when `sample1.var` is updated.