# How to save a list to a file and read it as a list type?

Tags: python, list, file

Say I have the list `score = [1,2,3,4,5]` and it gets changed while my program is running. How could I save it to a file so that next time the program is run I can access the changed list as a `list` type?

I have tried:

```
score=[1,2,3,4,5]

with open("file.txt", 'w') as f:
    for s in score:
        f.write(str(s) + '\n')

with open("file.txt", 'r') as f:
    score = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]


print(score)
```

But this results in the elements in the list being strings not integers.

Comment: Sounds like you might be interested in the `pickle` module.

Comment: The question should not have been tagged `pickle` just because *some* of the people answering thought it might be the best tool for the job. Tags should describe the **question**; i.e. the things that a potential answerer **needs to** know well in order to be able to answer.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I decided I didn't want to use a pickle because I wanted to be able to open the text file and change its contents easily during testing. Therefore, I did this:

```
score = [1,2,3,4,5]

with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    for s in score:
        f.write(str(s) +"\n")
```

```
score = []
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
  for line in f:
    score.append(int(line.strip()))
```

So the items in the file are read as integers, despite being stored to the file as strings.

Comment: Why do you think using the pickle is not easier than your suggestion?

Comment: @Hadij they want to be able to open it in a text editor

Answer (score 186):

You can use the `pickle`  module for that.
This module has two methods,

1. **Pickling(dump)**: Convert Python objects into a string representation.
2. **Unpickling(load)**: Retrieving original objects from a stored string representation.

https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/pickle.html

**Code**:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> with open("test", "wb") as fp:   #Pickling
...   pickle.dump(l, fp)
... 
>>> with open("test", "rb") as fp:   # Unpickling
...   b = pickle.load(fp)
... 
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

Also Json

1. dump/dumps: Serialize
2. load/loads: Deserialize

https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

**Code**:

```
>>> import json
>>> with open("test", "w") as fp:
...     json.dump(l, fp)
...
>>> with open("test", "r") as fp:
...     b = json.load(fp)
...
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Pickling can be potentially insecure. See https://www.synopsys.com/blogs/software-security/python-pickling/

Comment: Curious why you are naming binary `pkl` files with `txt` extension, or maybe am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @eric: yes it should not be, removed

Answer (score 69):

While the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28305183/11070463) works, you should really be using python's [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module (see end of post for comparison with `pickle`):

```py
import json

score=[1,2,3,4,5]

with open("file.json", 'w') as f:
    # indent=2 is not needed but makes the file human-readable 
    # if the data is nested
    json.dump(score, f, indent=2) 

with open("file.json", 'r') as f:
    score = json.load(f)

print(score)
```

**Advantages**:

1. `json` is a widely adopted and standardized data format, so non-python programs can easily read and understand the json files
2. `json` files are human-readable and easy to edit (plain text)
3. Any nested or non-nested list/dictionary structure can be saved to a `json` file (as long as all the contents are serializable).

**Disadvantages**:

1. The data is stored in plain-text (ie it's uncompressed), which makes it a slow and space-inefficient option for large amounts of data.
2. The contents of a list/dictionary need to be serializable before you can save it as a json. The `json` module will let you save strings, ints, floats, boolean, and None values, you'll need to write custom serialization and deserialization code to save objects, classes, and functions.

**`pickle` vs `json`, which one should I use?**:

- If you want to store something you know you're only ever going to use in the context of a python program, use `pickle`
- If you need to save data that isn't serializable by default (ie objects), save yourself the trouble and use `pickle`
- If you need a platform agnostic solution, use `json`
- If you need to be able to inspect and edit the data directly, use `json`
- If you need something robust and long-term, use `json` (`pickle` won't work correctly if you change the location of classes/files or make breaking changes to the code)

Answer (score 23):

If you don't want to use pickle, you can store the list as text and then evaluate it:

```
data = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
with open("test.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(str(data))

with open("test.txt", "r") as file:
    data2 = eval(file.readline())

# Let's see if data and types are same.
print(data, type(data), type(data[0]))
print(data2, type(data2), type(data2[0]))
```

> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] class 'list' class 'int'
>
> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] class 'list' class 'int'

Comment: Although this is an option, this is a very bad option. [You should avoid `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice). This is exactly what the `json` module in python is for.

Comment: Downvote; eval is way too dangerous in this context. Any malware or hacker (or appuser) who can edit the file can insert malicious code, and your program will end up running whatever code they put in there as the "value" being read is evalled.

Answer (score 10):

If you want you can use numpy's save function to save the list as file.
Say you have two lists

```
sampleList1=['z','x','a','b']
sampleList2=[[1,2],[4,5]]
```

here's the function to save the list as file, remember you need to keep the extension .npy

```
def saveList(myList,filename):
    # the filename should mention the extension 'npy'
    np.save(filename,myList)
    print("Saved successfully!")
```

and here's the function to load the file into a list

```
def loadList(filename):
    # the filename should mention the extension 'npy'
    tempNumpyArray=np.load(filename)
    return tempNumpyArray.tolist()
```

a working example

```
>>> saveList(sampleList1,'sampleList1.npy')
>>> Saved successfully!
>>> saveList(sampleList2,'sampleList2.npy')
>>> Saved successfully!

# loading the list now 
>>> loadedList1=loadList('sampleList1.npy')
>>> loadedList2=loadList('sampleList2.npy')

>>> loadedList1==sampleList1
>>> True

>>> print(loadedList1,sampleList1)

>>> ['z', 'x', 'a', 'b'] ['z', 'x', 'a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 6):

`pickle` and other serialization packages work.  So does writing it to a `.py` file that you can then import.

```
>>> score = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> 
>>> with open('file.py', 'w') as f:
...   f.write('score = %s' % score)
... 
>>> from file import score as my_list
>>> print(my_list)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. Make a clear distinction between data and code; don't store data _as_ code.

Comment: @Rawing: personally, I prefer using pickling or other methods... however, the SO asked how could it be done, and it's a valid way to do it.  If you look at the accepted answer, saving the list as a string only works in certain cases (where there are simple entries like `1,2,3`).  I'd also expect that my response provides the fastest approach.  Again, I'd use pickling when speed isn't needed, and a raw list object in when speed is needed.  There are some dangers of using an `import` to read the data, but those cases can be handled if needed. So we can agree to disagree.

Comment: I saw someone else use 'import' for small saved data recently. I had never thought of it. I think this might be a neat approach in a project of mine. If someone else decides that using this approach is something to try, and if memory is a concern, ```import sys; import mylist; del mylist, sys.modules['mylist']```. I haven't tried it in practice, yet, though -- just tested it out. I'll test it in practice tonight.

Comment: @OldWinterton: you may want to check this out: https://github.com/uqfoundation/klepto/blob/master/klepto/_archives.py#L828

Answer (score 6):

What I did not like with many answers is that it makes way too many system calls by writing to the file line per line. Imho it is best to join list with '\n' (line return) and then write it only once to the file:

```
mylist = ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
myfile = "file.txt"
with open(myfile, 'w') as f:
    f.write("\n".join(mylist))
```

and then to open it and get your list again:

```
with open(myfile, 'r') as f:
    mystring = f.read()
my_list = mystring.split("\n")
```

Comment: _"makes way too many system calls - one per line"_ - i really was thinking same when reading answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/ but then again; python programmers... can't blame lol.

Answer (score 1):

I am using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])
x.to_excel('temp.xlsx')
y = list(pd.read_excel('temp.xlsx')[0])
print(y)
```

Use this if you are anyway importing pandas for other computations.

Comment: You propose to use excel as the intermediate format, sounds like overhead, and also had always format issues with xls formats.

Answer (score 1):

```
errorlist = ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc', 'dddd']

f = open("filee.txt", "w")
f.writelines(nthstring + '\n' for nthstring in errorlist)

f = open("filee.txt", "r")
cont = f.read()
contentlist = cont.split()
print(contentlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem where I needed to read list saved as text file. The list had multiple layers so using split would not help.
For example:

```
list1.txt
[(1,2,3),['a','b'],'a1']
```

so what I did , I changed list.txt to list.py and then imported list from python file.
For example:

```
   list1.py
   a = [(1,2,3),['a','b'],'a1']
```

Then:

```
from list1 import a
print(a)
```