# Saving lists into .txt - python

Tags: python, list, file, save

I am quite new to programming and I am coding simple game in Python (case opening from CSGO). I have list with some things in it - example ["P250 - Iron Clad", "P2000 - Imperial Dragon"] and I am searching for the best way to save it to txt file after game closes, and then again read it after game starts. I have tried soo many ways but it still doesn't work rly. Can you suggest me some idea? Thanks. :-)

my current save code:

```
with open("userskins.txt", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(str(skinsall))
```

my current load code /DOESN'T WORK/ I don't know how to convert this type of str (more words at one item) into list

```
file2 = open("userskins.txt", "r")
skinsall = (file2.read())
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: The "best way" is not to cook up your own text-serialization format, and instead, rely on hardened formats like JSON.

Comment: Yes, I have edited the way I tried it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save a list to a file and read it as a list type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745500/how-to-save-a-list-to-a-file-and-read-it-as-a-list-type)

Comment: http://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to save a list of strings, both of which are JSON-serializable (along with booleans, many numeric types, and dictionaries), JSON is a popular way to do this.

Saving: Open a write file with `write_file = open(filename, "w")`. Save as JSON with `json.dump(your_list, write_file)`.

Loading: Open a read file with `read_file = open(filename, "r")`. Load JSON with `your_list = json.load(read_file)`.

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html

A few other formats you could try, each with their own pros/cons: CSV, XML, Python's native format (`repr(your_list)`).