# Trying to save a class (in a list) to a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, arraylist, save

I am trying to create a program where I can store NPCs in a game with certain attributes. Such as: Faction, personality, interests/hobbies. To achieve this, I have created an NPC class.

```
class NPC: #name, faction, position/job, character, interests, other
    def __init__ (self, name, faction, pos, char, inter, misc):
        self.name = name
        self.faction = faction
        self.pos = pos
        self.char = char
        self.inter = inter
        self.misc = misc
```

I have created various functions for this program, such as creating new ones, changing certain attributes on NPCs, removing them, printing them and sorting them. To store the NPCs, I append them to a list named "NPClist". I would like to know how to save this list to a .text file or something. So far I have tried the pickle module but that doesn't seem to work. (Sourced from: [How to save a list to a file and read it as a list type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745500/how-to-save-a-list-to-a-file-and-read-it-as-a-list-type/49209615#49209615))

```
with open("NPCs.text", "wb") as file:
    pickle.dump(NPClist, file)

with open("NPCs.text", "rb") as file:
    NPClist.append(pickle.load(file))
```

I have put the bottom one at the top of the program so that it will load it when the program is launched and the top one at the top of a loop so that it will save frequently. When I try starting the program I get an error message.

`AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'NPC' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>`

Is there another way to solve this problem or am I just doing pickle the wrong way?

Comment: do you need to use pickle?

Comment: I don't, that was just an example of what I had tried, I am open to new solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need are the attributes I would suggest just saving the attributes instead of trying to save the entire object, and make this process easier with some helper methods in NPC.

For instance:

```
class NPC:

    def dump(self):
        return [self.name, self.faction, self.pos, self.char, self.inter, self.misc]

    @staticmethod
    def build_npc(attributes):
        return NPC(*attributes)
```

And then you may deal with dumping like so:

```
NPClist = [NPC(...), NPC(...) ... ]

with open("NPCs.text", "wb") as file:
    pickle.dump([i.dump() for i in NPClist], file)
```

And loading like so:

```
with open("NPCs.text", "rb") as file:
    NPClist = [NPC.build_npc(attributes) for attributes in pickle.load(file)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class NPC: #name, faction, position/job, character, interests, other
    def __init__ (self, name, faction, pos, char, inter, misc):
        self.name = name
        self.faction = faction
        self.pos = pos
        self.char = char
        self.inter = inter
        self.misc = misc

NPCList = []

handsome_npc = NPC(name='n1c9', faction='Good People', pos='Developer',
                   char='', inter='', misc='')

# create other NPCs as needed

NPCList.append(handsome_npc)

with open('NPCS.text', 'w') as f:
    f.write('name,faction,pos\n')
    # add other attrs as wanted
    for npc in NPCList:
        f.write(f"{npc.name}, {npc.faction}, {npc.pos}")
        # add other attrs as wanted
        f.write('\n')
```

Tried to write something that's accessible to a beginner - might be a little verbose because of that.  Mark Tyler's answer is really good, too!

re: comment - you could access the file afterwards like so:

```
class NPC: #name, faction, position/job, character, interests, other
    def __init__ (self, name, faction, pos, char, inter, misc):
        self.name = name
        self.faction = faction
        self.pos = pos
        self.char = char
        self.inter = inter
        self.misc = misc

npclist_built_from_file = []
with open('NPCS.text', 'r') as f:
    NPCS_lines = f.readlines()
    for line in NPCS_lines[1:]: # skip the header line
        npc = NPC(name=line[0], faction=line[1], pos=line[2], char='', inter='', misc='')
        # I used empty strings for char/inter/misc because they were empty in the original
        # example, but you would just fill out line[3], line[4], line[5] for the rest if wanted.
        npclist_built_from_file.append(npc)
```

Then you could do whatever you wanted with the NPC objects in the list `npclist_built_from_file`

Comment: How would I go about loading that file after I've saved it?

Comment: Edited the answer to also answer this.

Answer (score 0):

```
import ast

def stringifyNPC(c):
  return str(c.__dict__)

def unStringifyNPC(s):
  n = NPC(None,None,None,None,None,None)
  n.__dict__ = ast.literal_eval(s)
  return n
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.