# How to keep old values in the list after running the program again

Tags: python, list

```
    TempList = []
    print("Welcome to Sensor Monitor")

   print("1- Submit Temperature")
   print("2- Temperature Report")
   print("0- Exit program")
    Decision= input("What would you like to do? ")

    if Decision == '2':
        n= len(TempList)
        x = sum(TempList)
        avgtemp = (x/n)
        print('Average temperature!', avgtemp)
        print('Max temperature:', TempList.max)
        print('Minimum temperature:', TempList.min)


    if Decision == '0':


        print("GoodBye")

    if Decision == '1':
        Temp= int(input("What is the temperature? "))
        if Temp <= -200 or Temp >= 200:
            error =  print("Temperature is out of range [-200 <= temp <= 200]")
        else:
            TempList.append(Temp)
            print(TempList)
            if max(TempList) == Temp or TempList.max < Temp:
                print("This is the highest temperature!")
            if min(TempList) > Temp:
                print("This is the smallest temperature!")
```

I'm trying to get the average temperature from my list but every time I run the program again I lose the previous value. and always end up with a single value in it, how do I keep the previous value while adding the new value?

Comment: You need to save data to a file then read the file each time the program starts. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save a list to a file and read it as a list type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745500/how-to-save-a-list-to-a-file-and-read-it-as-a-list-type)

Comment: Yes thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you run a program, the variables are stored in volatile memory (e.g. your RAM, registers, etc.). You'll have to change your code so it saves your data in persistent storage, whether through files, a database, or whatnot.