# How can I make a permanent 2d list(Python)

Tags: python, list, 2d, permanent

In my code, I want to have a list that when the file is closed, I can still access the filled list when rerunning it. For example, if I have a `list = [1]` in a file, I want it to be able to be filled permanently. Idk if that makes sense. Like `list = [1]` turns into `list = [1,2]`. Probably hardcoded.

Comment: write it to a file...then reread it from the file when you restart

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save a list to a file and read it as a list type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745500/how-to-save-a-list-to-a-file-and-read-it-as-a-list-type)

Comment: @BlueLightning42 That is what I ended up doing, thank you.

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 I found a simpler version by doing
 ``` with open('Tasks.txt','r') as file:
        data = file.readlines()```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using  `with open('Tasks.txt','r') as file: data = file.readlines()`
to open the file

```
line = data[i].split(" ")
```

to get a specific line and

```
        file.writelines(data)
```

to write it back into the file or```
with open('Tasks.txt','w') as file:
file.writelines(data)