# python write list to file

Tags: python, arrays, list, file

from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/python-write-a-list-to-a-file) post, I've been using the following code to write a list/array to a file:

```
with open ("newhosts.txt",'w') as thefile:
    for item in hostnameIP:
      thefile.write("%s\n" % item)
```

where `hostnameIP` is:

`[['localhost', '::1'], ['localhost', '::1'], ['localhost', '::1']]`

In the file, I get the output:

```
['localhost', '::1']
['localhost', '::1']
['localhost', '::1']
```

when I need to to say

```
localhost, ::1
localhost, ::1
localhost, ::1
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: both answers good cheers guys!

Comment: Which you are going to accept? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
with open ("newhosts.txt", "w") as thefile:
    for item in hostnameIP:
        thefile.write("%s\n" % ", ".join(item))
```

This way each part of item will be printed with an ", " as seperator.

But if you want to make the code even shorter, you can also join each item with a newline:

```
with open ("newhosts.txt", "w") as thefile:
    thefile.write("\n".join(map(", ".join, hostnameIP)))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
with open ("newhosts.txt",'w') as thefile:
    for item in hostnameIP:
      thefile.write("%s, %s\n" % (item[0], item[1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the csv module simply calling writerows on your list of lists:

```
import csv
lines = [['localhost', '::1'], ['localhost', '::1'], ['localhost', '::1']]
with open ("newhosts.txt",'w') as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    wr.writerows(lines)
```

Output:

```
localhost,::1
localhost,::1
localhost,::1
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see you have a list with lists as elements. This is why you get the result that you get. Try the following code (see the minor change on the third line) and you will get the wanted result.

```
with open ("newhosts.txt",'w') as thefile:
    for item in hostnameIP:
      thefile.write("%s\n" % ', '.join(item))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are currently printing string representations of the lists to the file.  Since you are only interested in the lists' items, you can use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and argument unpacking to extract them:

```
thefile.write("{}, {}\n".format(*item))
```