# Python: Break DAT files in modules and search specific lines

Tags: python, database, file

I have a large DAT file of this type:

```
//
AC  T00020
OS  rat, Rattus norvegicus
BS  R02959; HS$APOA1_02; Quality: 6; APOA1, G000203; human, Homo sapiens.
I have a large dat file of this type:
//
AC  T00024
OS  rat, Rattus norvegicus
BS  R00135; HS$APOA1_01; Quality: 6; APOA1, G000203; human, Homo sapiens.
//
AC  T00025
OS  human, Homo sapiens
BS  R02119; ANF$CONS_01; Quality: 4.
BS  R02333; MOUSE$ALBU_12; Quality: 6; Alb, G000464; mouse, Mus musculus.
BS  R02334; MOUSE$ALBU_13; Quality: 6; Alb, G000464; mouse, Mus musculus.
//
AC  T00027
OS  clawed frog, Xenopus
BS  R02120; AP1$CONS; Quality: 6.
//
```

I first want to break it in modules where it starts and ends with '//'
Then I want to keep only those modules having 'OS human, HomosSapiens' in them.

I am writing a python script to achieve this, but i am not able to break it in modules yet.
I am trying it in Python 3.

Finally i want to keep this part of the dat file:

```
AC  T00025
OS  human, Homo sapiens
BS  R02119; ANF$CONS_01; Quality: 4.
BS  R02333; MOUSE$ALBU_12; Quality: 6; Alb, G000464; mouse, Mus musculus.
BS  R02334; MOUSE$ALBU_13; Quality: 6; Alb, G000464; mouse, Mus musculus.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Open file and read](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm) the contents, (not line by line) using `f.read()`.

[Split](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) by a chosen character or string.

```
# puts each text block as an item in a list
items = s.split('//')
```

[Write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/writing-a-list-to-a-file-with-python) the results.

Comment: I am new to programming. I have read and opened the file. I want to break the lines in between the '//' into diff parts. How should i do it?

Comment: Added the code. You should split the string with `'//'` as a delimiter. then you can pick an item like this `items[2]` or print it all like this `for item in items: print(item)`

Comment: I am now not able to go to the next line.. Can you please solve for the entire problem mentioned above.
`code`

file = "file.dat"
with open(file, 'r') as f:
 line = f.readline()
 items = line.split('//')
 for item in items:
  print(item)

It obviously gets stuck at the first line itself and doesn't proceed to the next line.. Also I must retain those blocks which have OS - human..

Comment: Don't read one line, read the whole file. I am sorry but I cannot solve the entire problem. Stack Overflow is not for asking other people to write code for you. You have a simple task of reading the whole file like `data = f.read()` and then manipulate it with `data.split('//')` and other string methods python offer. Good luck!

Comment: Understood  my mistake. I was trying to take a single line.

Comment: @Amy I edited the answer, If it satisfies you please accept it. Thanks.