# Writing list to file -- File written to not found

Tags: python, file, loops, python-3.x, user-input

I am using Python 3.

This is a script that i am in the process of writing. It asks for a name/birthday, takes that input, and appends it into a list. The list is then written to another file.

I have done research on this and can't find why it isn't working.

Here is my code:

```
print("""Enter the name and birthday of the person like this:
Adam 1/29
""")

all_birthdays = [ "none so far" ]

while True:
    birthday = input("> ").upper()

    if birthday == "":
        break

    if birthday == "LIST":
        print(all_birthdays)

    if birthday not in all_birthdays:
        all_birthdays.append(birthday)
    else:
        print("This name/birthday is already known")

birthday_list = open('test.txt','w')

for bday in all_birthdays
    birthday_list.write("%s\n" %bday)
```

---

**SECOND EDIT:** I added code ( bottom-most for loop and the create file ). It worked, but i can't seem to even find the file anywhere. Any help? How can i find it and open it?
This code was found at: [Writing a list to a file with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/writing-a-list-to-a-file-with-python)

Comment: You're missing the brackets for your function call to (). After adding these brackets the code works fine for me.

Comment: Dartmouth means the `upper` function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
 birthday = input("> ").upper
```

Should be:

```
 birthday = input("> ").upper()
```

The former assigns the `upper` function to the variable `birthday` rather than the uppercase of the input string.

Comment: This worked, Thanks! Added another question. Do you have an idea for that one?

Comment: No problem. It will only write the file once the main loop exits after you enter a blank line.

Comment: Probably best to accept this answer and ask additional questions as a new question.

Comment: Yeah good idea. I'm new to Stack and to Python, so thanks for the help!