# Python: Write list to file, line by line

Tags: python, list, file

I want to write the following `list` to file, each time from new line.

```
bill_List = [total_price, type_of_menu, type_of_service, amount_of_customers, discount]
```

I tried to use this code but it just overwrites the text file. Could somebody help me? Where is my mistake?

```
# attempt #1
f = open("Bills.txt", "w")
f.write("\n".join(map(lambda x: str(x), bill_List)))
f.close()


# attempt #2
# Open a file in write mode
f = open('Bills.txt', 'w')
for item in bill_List:
f.write("%s\n" % item)
# Close opend file
f.close()

# attempt #3

with open('Bills.txt', 'w') as f:
for s in bill_List:
    f.write(s + '\n')

with open('Bills.txt', 'r') as f:
bill_List = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]

# attempt #4
with open('Bills.txt', 'w') as out_file:
out_file.write('\n'.join(
    bill_List))
```

Comment: Why are you formatting your code as strings?

Comment: This is already answered here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/writing-a-list-to-a-file-with-python

Comment: @famargar, I tried this also, but `for item in thelist:
  thefile.write("%s\n" % item)` also overwrite file or I do something wrong (

Comment: @AndrewJaffe, yes that don't have a sense, I change format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for 'a' instead of 'w' for the buffering parameter:

```
with open('Bills.txt', 'a') as out_file:
    [...]
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open

Comment: No problem. While you are at it, consider also `writelines()`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=writelines#file.writelines (I am not sure it applies to your case)