# Python Write lists in a file

Tags: python, arrays, list, file

My question is: How can I write lists in a file?

So:

```
list = ["damn","bro"]
correct_list = "\n".join(list)
file = open("test.txt", "w")
```

How do I write this into a file now that it's a list?
So in the file:

```
damn
bro
```

I already tried it but it just stand behind each other without whitespace

Comment: Do you want to know how to read from a file and store it as a list or take all the elements of a list and write them to a file?

Comment: @Buzz I want to take all elements of a list and write them to a file.

Comment: the solution linked to above is wrong, the OP tries to write into a file and not read from a file. I've flagged this question so hopefully the duplicate link is removed

Comment: @Lucas in your code there's a line missing where you actually write into the file. it should read `file.write(correct_list)`. With this it works.

Comment: also: `list` is a reserved python keyword, you should not name your variable like this as you might into problems later, try `l` for example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing a list to a file with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/writing-a-list-to-a-file-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

First, you probably shouldn't use `list` because it is a reserved word in python.([link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list)) You could use almost anything else. I usually use `lst`

You need to actually put it in the file. Your code is missing:

```
file.write(correct_list)
```

this will actually write the string to the file.

You can also try something like this:

```
lst=["damn","bro"]
file = open("test.txt", "w")
for item in lst:
    file.write(item+"\n")
```

This will loop over each item in the list and write them one at a time to the file with a new line at the end

Also make sure you close the file when you are done with it:

```
file.close()
```