# Split python list objects separated by u' '

Tags: python

I have a python list object containing elements as follows:

```
[u'Sentence 1 blabla.'],
[u'Sentence 2 blabla.'],
...
```

I want to extract the contents inside ' ' present in the list and store each as separate lines in a text file. Please help me with the same

Comment: Have you tried the normal text file IO?  What have you tried?

Comment: What does this have to do with splitting?

Comment: I need to extract the string of each list element(sentences) enclosed in the ' ' quotes and then write to a file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing a list to a file with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/writing-a-list-to-a-file-with-python)

Comment: @Anu You **already have** those strings. No need to extract anything.

Answer (score 1):

`u'blablabla'` is `Unicode`. You can convert it into `string` using `str(unicode)`

Example:

```
a = [[u'qweqwe'],[u'asdasd']]
```

`str(a[0][0])` will be string `qweqwe`.
Now you can write it into file as usual.

Try this example for clarity:

```
a = [[u'qweqwe'],[u'asdasd']]
print type(a[0][0])
print type(str(a[0][0]))
```

Output:

```
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'str'>
```

Comment: Thanks Jithin. I will try this out

Comment: @Anu, Upvote and/or accept the solution if found useful - makes it easy for others to pick the solution. Let comments be informative.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Given that you have a list of lists, I am going to assume that you are going to convert the given list from unicode to an UTF8 string. For this lets have a function `convertList` which takes a `list of lists` as an input

So your initial value for `l` would be

```
[[u'Sentence 1 blabla.'],
[u'Sentence 2 blabla.'],
...]
```

Notice that this is a list of lists. Now for each list item, loop through the items within that list and convert them all to UTF8.

```
def convertList(l):
    newlist = []
    for x in l:
        templ = [item.encode('UTF8') for item in x]
        newlist.append(templ)
    return newlist

l = [[u'Sentence 1 blabla.'], [u'Sentence 2 blabla.']]
l = convertList(l) # This updates the object you have
# Now do the filewrite operations here.
f = open('myfile.txt','w')
for iList in l:
    for items in iList:
        f.write(items+'\n')
f.close()
```

This will write to the file `myfile.txt` as follows

`Sentence 1 blabla.
Sentence 2 blabla.`