# Writing lists to a text file in string format

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, text, text-files

This may be a simple question however, I'm currently doing an assessment and I'm on the final section.

What I need to do is write a list to a text file, but in string format. What I mean by this is for example if I want the list `['the', 'cat', 'sat', 'on', 'the', 'mat']` if I want to write this list to a text file it writes it in this format, when I need it to be written in continuous prose so `the cat sat on the mat`. I'm not sure how to do this? I tried adding `str` before the `.write` command but this doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: `with open('path/to/file', 'w') as outfile: outfile.write(' '.join(myList))`

Comment: You're asking how to convert a list to a string? This is likely covered in just about every python tutorial out there.

Comment: @BryanOakley Sorry Bryan, I just didn't know exactly how to do it :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing a list to a file with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/writing-a-list-to-a-file-with-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
`F.writeline(" ".join(your_list))`

Comment: Thank you very much Bipul Jain! This solved my problem!