# how to write two lists into a file

Tags: python

I am having trouble with my code which is meant to create a file and write a list of words and a list of numbers into the file. The code does not create a file at all. Here it is:

```
sentence=input('please enter a sentence: ')
list_of_words=sentence.split()
words_with_numbers=enumerate(list_of_words, start=1)
filename = 'fileoflists.txt'
with open('fileoflists', 'w+') as file:
    file.write(str(list_of_words) + '/n' + str(words_with_numbers) + '/n')
```

thanks

Comment: If no file seems to be created, it may be in another place? How did you run your script?

Comment: Cannot duplicate - I ran your code and it created the `fileoflists` file. BTW, did you want `"\n"` newlines?

Answer (score 0):

Reference [this question for info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/writing-a-list-to-a-file-with-python). Try this:

```
sentence=input('please enter a sentence: ')
list_of_words=sentence.split()
words_with_numbers=enumerate(list_of_words, start=1)
filename = 'fileoflists.txt'

with open('fileoflists', 'w+') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(['%s \n %s'%(x[0],x[1]) 
               for x in zip(list_of_words, words_with_numbers)])+'\n')
```

Comment: OP uses `str()` to convert the lists to strings and that is literally what he asks for in his question. Your solution seems like a reasonable way to write the contents of the lists... but we may need clarification of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Running your code it does create the file but see that you are defining the file name in `filename` with the value of `"fileoflists.txt"` but then you do not use that parameter but just create a file (not a text file).

Also it does not print what you are expecting. for the list it prints the string representation of the list but for the `words_with_numbers` it prints the `__str__` of the iterator returned by the `enumerate`.

See changes in code bellow:

```
sentence = input('please enter a sentence: ')
list_of_words = sentence.split()
# Use list comprehension to format the output the way you want it
words_with_numbers = ["{0} {1}".format(i,v)for i, v in enumerate(list_of_words, start=1)]

filename = 'fileoflists.txt'
with open(filename, 'w+') as file: # See that now it is using the paramater you created
    file.write('\n'.join(list_of_words)) # Notice \n and not /n
    file.write('\n')
    file.write('\n'.join(words_with_numbers))
```