# How can we store dynamic array values permanently

Tags: python, arrays

I tried to store array values in python but after inserting values I close the IDE and open it prints the array values null. How can we store dynamic array values permanently in python it's like load and write values from a file.......

Comment: write a file and don't use the IDE to store data

Comment: What you did may be obvious to you, but you need to be explicit with us. *How* did you try to store them? If your question is how to write to and read from a file, it has surely been asked before.

Comment: how can we permanently store array values in python???

Comment: There are many options for writing something to a file, but the cleanest or most appropriate depends on what kind of values you have. Is it an numpy array or list? Are your values numbers, strings or objects?

Answer (score 0):

> You could use
>
> - json
> - pickle
>
> for permanent storage.

```
if STORAGEFILE EXISTS:
  Var = STORAGEFILE_CONTENT
else:
  Var = currentVal
ON_EXIT:
  Update Var to STORAGEFILE
```

Comment: it's a dynamic array so i need to update it every time also it's loads first when programme start

Comment: @ArunDas refer this link for pickle http://www.diveintopython3.net/serializing.html

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to write the array values to a txt-file. Then you can close your IDE and later open it and get the array from the txt-file.

[Writing a list to a file with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/writing-a-list-to-a-file-with-python)