# List sorted-Python card game

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a card game that contains a list of cards in a players hand from top to bottom and I need to check up to what point the cards list break from the order of small to large(from top to bottom). I am not able to use any sort of GUI's.

For example,
cards in players hand:
23
24
12
5-check for the fifth element in the list that is properly sorted
4
3
2
1

Comment: So show us what you have tried so far

Comment: if hands1[0]>hands1[1]:
        solitaireScore=5
        if hands1[1]>hands1[2]:
            solitaireScore=10

Comment: but the problem is I'm trying to make it like a nested if statement but don't know how to do it. I want to check if the first card is greater than the second card if this is true than proceed. to the other condition etc.

Comment: You might consider using dictionary like {"23":4, "24": 3, "12":2, "5": 1} and then if use sorted(your_dict)  - like `sorted(yourdict.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): (v,k)) ` - using dictionary would give you O(1) time, vs using list

Comment: @dmitryro But sorting itself is `O(nlogn)`?

Comment: Python's `sorted` function, applied to a collection, should not require implementing anything other than that, so time is not a real concern.

Answer (score 2):

Code commented for explanation reasons, hth:

```
cardsInHand = [23,24,25,23,27,4]  # all your cards

cardsInOrder = []                 # empty list, to be filled with in order cards
lastCard = None  

for card in cardsInHand:                  # loop all cards in hand
    if not lastCard or lastCard < card:       # if none taken yet or smaller
        cardsInOrder.append(card)                 # append to result
        lastCard = card                           # remember for comparison to next card
    else:                                     # not in order
        break                                     # stop collecting more cards into list 

print(cardsInOrder)               # print all
```

Output:

```
[23, 24, 25]
```

If you need the *unordered* part of your hand as well, you can get that by:

```
unorderedCards = cardsInHand[len(cardsInOrder):] # list-comp based length of ordered cards
```

Comment: also, can you help me solve a problem with writing to a list, every time I exit off the file and add more info it wipes the previous data?

Comment: @SimeonGeorge there are plenty of questions regarding "writing to file" for python on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/writing-a-list-to-a-file-with-python just as an example. Search them. Or read here: [reading-and-writing-files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)