# simplify python print

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list:

```
row = [u'28d07ef48e40', u'373ac79f615f', u'a3ec4faddbec', u'c0195f9568c6', u'cc4ebc7b826c', u'ccdfdb826c', u'cc4fa826c', u'cc4eeesb826c', u'ccfesb826c']
```

my print is

```
fw.write("%s %s <%s> [%s] %s %s (%s) %s: %s" %(str(row[0]),str(row[1]),str(row[2]),str(row[3]),str(row[4]),str(row[5]),str(row[6]),str(row[7]),str(row[8])))
```

How can I simplify this python print?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/writing-a-list-to-a-file-with-python

Comment: First step would be to remove the unnecessary `str()` calls.

Comment: Also, `*row` will save you `row[0],row[1],row[2]...`

Comment: You are not specifying that you are writing to a file. What you are doing is not printing. Why do you need some entries of the list in brackets and others not? What is the real goal here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your Python version, you can:

For `Python 3.6` and later use new `format-strings`, which are the **most-recommended** approach:

```
row = [u'28d07ef48e40', u'373ac79f615f', u'a3ec4faddbec', u'c0195f9568c6', u'cc4ebc7b826c', u'ccdfdb826c', u'cc4fa826c', u'cc4eeesb826c', u'ccfesb826c']

fw.write(f'{row[0]} {row[1]} [{row[2]}] ...')
```

For lower versions of Python 3, you can use `str.format()`, which is **recommended** over `%`-formatting:

```
fw.write('{} {} <{}> [{}] {} {} ({}) {}: {}'.format(row[0], row[1], row[2], ...)
```

For Python 2 you continue with `%`-formatting, but you dont need to call `str()` on arguments - it is done automatically:

```
fw.write("%s %s <%s> [%s] %s %s (%s) %s: %s" % tuple(row))
```

Comment: You're missing an `f` in front of your Python 3.6 string. Edited for you

Comment: @ycx sorry, I occasionally have overwritten your edit and thus deprived your +2, but then upvoted one of your good answers for you to get scored

Answer (score 1):

you can try using the join function

`row = [u'28d07ef48e40', u'373ac79f615f', u'a3ec4faddbec', u'c0195f9568c6', u'cc4ebc7b826c', u'ccdfdb826c', u'cc4fa826c', u'cc4eeesb826c', u'ccfesb826c']`

```
fw.write(' '.join(row))
```

this works beacuse the join function joins everything in the list into the string

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. It would be great if you could explain to us how and why your code solves the OP's problem as code itself is not always easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

The format string is in it's simplest form. What you can "simplify" is the conversion to string:

```
"%s %s <%s> [%s] %s %s (%s) %s: %s".format(map(str, row))
```

`map(str, row)` will call `str()` on all elements n row, and returns a list in 2.7, and iterator in 3.7.

Comment: `str()` is not needed there.

Answer (score 0):

The *row operator will pack the list