# AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Good day everyone! I have 2 files txt and csv  with numbers and I would like to compare and delete from 1st file numbers matching with a numbers in second file. Data and df_row are Datagrams.

For example: 
my first file consist

```
12354564
25345754
23545454
11565654
46456456
```

and my second file consist

```
23545454
11565654
46456456
```

so result should be

```
12354564
25345754
```

My code:

```
result = set(data).difference(set(df_row))
result.to_csv("part1left.txt")
```

but there is an error 
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

Comment: Im so sorry I couldnt edit as a code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `data` and `df_row` are `Series` for your solution need convert output to `list` and then to `Series`:

```
result = set(data).difference(set(df_row))
pd.Series(list(result)).to_csv("part1left.txt", index=False)
```

Or write set to file in [pure python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6791534):

```
result = set(data).difference(set(df_row))
with open("part1left.txt", 'w') as file_handler:
    for item in result:
        file_handler.write("{}\n".format(item))
```

Pandas only solution with filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and inverting mask by `~`:

```
s = data[~data.isin(set(df_row))].drop_duplicates()
s.to_csv("part1left.txt", index=False)
```

EDIT:

If need create `Series` from files:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""12354564
25345754
23545454
11565654
46456456"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename1.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), squeeze=True, header=None, dtype=str)
print (data)
0    12354564
1    25345754
2    23545454
3    11565654
4    46456456
Name: 0, dtype: int64


temp=u"""23545454
11565654
46456456"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename2.csv'
df_row = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), squeeze=True, header=None, dtype=str)
print (df_row)
0    23545454
1    11565654
2    46456456
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Comment: There is an Error :    TypeError: 'set' type is unordered

Comment: Thank u very much! but i have trouble when I use Pandas solution t is makes numbers with xxx.0 sample in a "part1left.txt" file. I didnt get how is possible)

Comment: - Im so sorry, but could u explain me why I still can find some numbers from second file in first if we dropped them? 1 file is data, secons is df_row. so as an  output I have to delete numbers from first file if they match to numbers in second.((

Comment: @BakhytgulAzhigaliyeva - if check `print (data.tolist())` and `print (df_row.tolist())` there are no whitespaces? Also another problem should be one or second values are not strings, need all values like strings. So then use `data = data.astype(str)` and `df_row = df_row.astype(str)`

Comment: @BakhytgulAzhigaliyeva - Data are condidental? Is possible share it?

Comment: According to print (data.tolist()) is still in a process. didnt give any output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196688/discussion-between-jezrael-and-bakhytgul-azhigaliyeva).