# Saving model history on google cloud storage

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am running a tensorflow job on google ai-platform. After the model is trained I want to save model.history to file. Since I need to write to a cloud storage bucket I use tf.io.write_file. 
I have tried the following:

```
hist=mymodel.fit(training_dataset_input,epochs=num_epochs,steps_per_epoch=int(training_samples/batch_size),validation_data=validation_dataset_input,validation_steps=1,verbose=1,callbacks[mycallbacks,tensorboard_cb,csv_logger])

tf.io.write_file(gs://<nameofbucket>/<nameoffile>,hist.history)
```

I get he following error message:

```
ValueError: Attempt to convert a value ({'loss': [355.3313500958558, 313.9355358472616], 'mean_squared_error': [355.3312, 313.93536], 'find_rms': [14.733875, 13.815437], 'val_loss': [292.5752868652344, 270.8216857910156], 'val_mean_squared_error': [292.5753, 270.8217], 'val_find_rms': [13.506351, 12.935535]}) with an unsupported type (<class 'dict'>) to a Tensor.
```

It looks like `hist.history` is a dictionary with strings as keys and lists as values. How can I get `hist.history` in the right format so that it can be written to file using `tf.io.write_file`?

Comment: have you tried using `tf.io.Gfile.gfile.write()` or `pandas` ? Link: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/gfile/GFile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to convert the dictionary into a list using [this](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-convert-a-dictionary-to-a-list-in-Python) and then save it ([this can help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/writing-a-list-to-a-file-with-python)).

If you want to visualize the saved data easily, you can maybe save it as csv ([this can help](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-save-a-Python-Dictionary-to-CSV-file)).

Hope it can suits your problem!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the answers. I found that a combination of your answer worked for me. In order to write any string I want to a file and format it as I like I can use:

```
with tf.io.gfile.GFile(gs://<bucket>/<filename>,"w") as file:
        file.write(<any string object>)
```

It also worked to do:

```
json.dumps(str(hist.history))
```

I needed to convert the whole history object to a string since it contains floats.

Answer (score 1):

[The docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/write_file) say that the arg 'contents' should be a Tensor of type string. scalar.

I could think of the following:
If you only just want to store your history with the TF library and no more processing will be performed after, you could use json.dumps to get a string from your dict and save it.

On the other hand, you can [Store objects to GCS Buckets via API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-code_sample) with Python so there will be no need for extra processing.