# Trouble writing some tabular content to a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've written a script in python to get some tabular content from a webpage and my script can parse them accordingly. However, the problem is I can't write them to a text file. When I try to write, the script throws an error pointing at the very last line `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list`.

[Site link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Intel_processors)

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Intel_processors"

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")

with open("tabular_content.txt", "w", newline="", encoding="UTF-8") as outfile:              
    for items in soup.find("table",class_="wikitable").find_all("tr"):
        data = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.find_all(["th","td"])]
        print(data)
        outfile.write(data)
```

***How can I write the tabular data to a text file?***

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/writing-a-list-to-a-file-with-python

Answer (score 0):

This script will save the tabular data to `'\t'`-separated csv file.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Intel_processors"

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")

with open("file.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="UTF-8") as outfile:
    for items in soup.find("table",class_="wikitable").find_all("tr"):
        data = [item.get_text(strip=True).replace('\n', ' ') for item in items.find_all(["th","td"])]
        print(data)
        outfile.write('\t'.join(data) + '\n')
```

The result in LibreOffice:

[image]