# List of files in two separate file folders (directories) is retrieved. How do I get what prints in the terminal to print into a new text document?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have a function that retrieves a list of files from two separate directories (file folders) that the user chooses in my Tkinter GUI window. The list of all the files in both of the directories prints in the visual studio code terminal just fine, but how do I get the list of files from these two directories to print to a new text file?

```
    Input_1 = entry_field1.get() #Retrieving what the user inputed into entry field 1.
    Input_2 = entry_field2.get() #Retrieving what the user inputed into entry field 2.
    file_list_1=os.listdir(Input_1) #Listing the files from directory 1.
    file_list_2=os.listdir(Input_2) #Listing the files from directory 2.
    print (file_list_1) #Printing the files in the terminal window.
    print (file_list_2) #Printing the files in the terminal window.
```

Comment: Are you asking the basic question of how to write data to a file? The source of the data is irrelevant. Writing to files is covered in many python tutorials.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing a list to a file with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/writing-a-list-to-a-file-with-python)

Comment: correct. I want to write data to a file.

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple ways to do this, both using the `open()` function. The official documentation is here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html.

## **Python 3 `print()` Statement**

### *Official docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html*

In python 3, the print statement is a function with additional parameters.
One of these parameters is helpful here: the `file` parameter.

To print to file:

```
>>> print('hello', file = open('hello.txt','w'))
```

## **Traditional `.write()` function**

### *Official docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html*

The write function takes one argument: a string.
To write to a file, first `open()` it.

```
>>> my_File = open('hello.txt', 'w') # the 'w' means that we're in write mode
>>> my_File.write('This is text')    # Now we need to close the file
>>> my_File.close()
```