# How to write a list to a file in Google Cloud Storage using Google Cloud Functions with Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to write members of a list into a file in a bucket in Cloud Storage using Cloud Functions.

I found [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-python) page showing how to upload a file to my bucket, but what I need is to loop through the members of my list and write them to the file in Cloud Storage.

I need to be able to do this using Cloud Functions, which reads from my Google Cloud SQL database. I want to be able to store the data from certain tables in my PostreSQL database as a file in Cloud Storage.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it done with the following python code:

```
import datetime
import logging
import os
import sqlalchemy
from google.cloud import storage
import pandas as pd

# Remember - storing secrets in plaintext is potentially unsafe. Consider using
# something like https://cloud.google.com/kms/ to help keep secrets secret.
db_user = "<DB_USER>"#os.environ.get("DB_USER")
db_pass = "<DB_PASS>"#os.environ.get("DB_PASS")
db_name = "<DB_NAME>"#os.environ.get("DB_NAME")
cloud_sql_connection_name = "<Cloud SQL Instance Connection Name>"#os.environ.get("CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME")
logger = logging.getLogger()

# [START cloud_sql_postgres_sqlalchemy_create]
db = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    # Equivalent URL:
    # postgres+pg8000://<db_user>:<db_pass>@/<db_name>?unix_sock=/cloudsql/<cloud_sql_instance_name>/.s.PGSQL.5432
    sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(
        drivername='postgres+pg8000',
        username=db_user,
        password=db_pass,
        database=db_name,
        query={
            'unix_sock': '/cloudsql/{}/.s.PGSQL.5432'.format(
                cloud_sql_connection_name)
        }
    ),
    # ... Specify additional properties here.
    pool_size=5,
    max_overflow=2,
    pool_timeout=30,  # 30 seconds
    pool_recycle=1800,  # 30 minutes
)

def read_source_data(request):
    bucket_name = <YOUR_BUCKET_NAME>
    folder_name = "sample_files"
    file_name = "test.txt"

    with db.connect() as conn:
        sales_records = conn.execute(
            "SELECT * FROM sales;"
        ).fetchall()

    if len(sales_records) > 0:
        #for val in sales_records:
            #print(val)
        df = pd.DataFrame(sales_records)
        df.columns = sales_records[0].keys()
        create_file(bucket_name, "sample_files/test.txt", df)
        return "Done!"
    else:
        print("Nothing!")
        return "Nothing!"

def create_file(bucketname, path, records_read):
  storage_client = storage.Client()
  bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucketname)
  blob = storage.Blob(
        name=path,
        bucket=bucket,
    )

  content = records_read.to_csv(index=False)#'\n'.join(map(str, records_read))

  blob.upload_from_string(
        data=content,
        content_type='text/plain',
        client=storage_client,
    )
```

I stitched this together from multiple code snippets and as not-a-python-developer I'm pretty sure there are better ways of getting this done.
I then deployed my function using

```
gcloud deployment-manager deployments  create
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you simply need to loop your list in Python and write the results
  to a file, you can use any of the multiple Python examples online or
  in Stack Overflow, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/899176/9146820) one:

  ```
  with open('your_file.txt', 'w') as f:
      for item in my_list:
          f.write("%s\n" % item)
  ```

  That is of course, depending on how your list looks like, the data, and the file type you need to write to Cloud Storage; those would have to be replaced according to your needs.
- To connect from your Cloud Function to your Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL
  database you can follow the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-functions). One example using
  `SQLAlchemy` and `Unix` sockets is:

  ```
     db = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
         # Equivalent URL:
         # postgres+pg8000://<db_user>:<db_pass>@/<db_name>?unix_sock=/cloudsql/<cloud_sql_instance_name>/.s.PGSQL.5432
         sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(
             drivername='postgres+pg8000',
             username=db_user,
             password=db_pass,
             database=db_name,
             query={
                 'unix_sock': '/cloudsql/{}/.s.PGSQL.5432'.format(
                     cloud_sql_connection_name)
             }
         ),
     )
  ```

  Where `db_user`, `db_pass` and `db_name` would have to be replaced with your database's username, password and the database's
  name.
- The [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-python) you referenced mentions how to upload a blob to Cloud
  Storage using Python as you are probably aware, so once the data is
  extracted from the database and written to  `your_file.txt` for
  example, you can upload it to Cloud Storage with:

  ```
  from google.cloud import storage


  def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
      """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
      bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
      source_file_name = "local/path/to/file/your_file.txt"
      destination_blob_name = "storage-object-name"

      storage_client = storage.Client()
      bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
      blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

      blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)

      print(
          "File {} uploaded to {}.".format(
              source_file_name, destination_blob_name
          )
      )
  ```

  Replace `your-bucket-name` with the name of your Cloud Storage bucket, `local/path/to/file/your_file.txt` with the local path to your file, and `storage-object-name` with the name and extension you want the file to have once it's uploaded to your Cloud Storage bucket.

Putting all those together, you can achieve what you're looking for.