# How to send a list to a txt file in list forms?

Tags: python, list, file

so my question is simple, how can I write my list in a text file in a form  list. (See the code bellow to understand what I mean). Thanks you

addlist.py

```
data = []
#List data
data.append("Test1")
data.append("Test2")

#Send list to files.
with open("newlist.txt", "w") as f:
    for item in data:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

So when I run this code, it write the data in my txt files but not as a list. I want the data in a list.

newlist.txt

```
Test1
Test2
```

Comment: Show what you expect to be written to the file.

Comment: "I want the data '*in a list*'"  What do you mean by '*in a list*' in this context?  Enclosed by square brackets and separated by commas?  Just write an open square bracket at the start and a comma after each line except the last and a close square bracket at the end...

Comment: **Please clarify your question.** Both the comments above are good, and have been completely ignored.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing a list to a file with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/writing-a-list-to-a-file-with-python)

Comment: I tried to edit the title of this post to something slightly more accurate/correct, but I was unable to submit it because SO detects that this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
with open("newlist.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(data))
```

you are writing in the file exactly what you get when you use `print(data)`

Comment: thanks you, this is what i was looking for. it working!

Comment: Yes i Will but i can't rn, it say I can in 6minut, But I have a question question, If I want the list to be vertical instead of horizontal, I know I need to add "\n" but i dont know where

Comment: you can use `f.write('[\n  ' + '\n  '.join(data) + '\n]')`

Comment: but it look like this ```[
 Test1,
 Test2,
]```

Comment: isnt suppose to look like this: list = ["test1", "test2"]

Comment: so `Test1` it is not a string?

Comment: they are some objects?

Comment: I need to look it like a real list. like ``` list = ["test1", "Test2"]

Comment: use  `f.write('list = ' + '[\n  ' + '\n  '.join( data) + '\n]')` if you want the list to apear verticaly

Comment: @tiberhockey I got your point, was about quotes character, so can use: `f.write( '[\n  ' + '\n  '.join('"%s"' % e for e in data) + '\n]'`

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is that the output is in JSON format. For that try this:

```
import json

f.write(json.dumps(data))
```