# How to get a set of words and print in alphabetical order in the output?

Tags: python

```
import pickle`f=open('/home/nikan/Desktop/Linux os/text/word.txt', 'rb')
```

pickle.load(f)`

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: sort works on arrays

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Nikan! Please post the code you have tried so far so we can easily see what your issue is.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.

Comment: Also note that we expect you to research solutions on your own, before posting here.  There are many tutorials on sorting.

Comment: This inputs a single word, not a list of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that only a single word was inputted and the sort method has been invoked on it.

Let's get multiple words, append them to a list and sort them:

```
input_words = []

# Get input words
word = input('Please enter word\n')
# As long as word is not "stop"
while word != 'stop':
    # Get new input word
    input_words.append(word)
    # Append to list of words
    word = input('Please enter word\n')

# Sort words
input_words.sort()

# Print sorted list of words
print(input_words)

# Write to file
with open('your_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in input_words:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Hi, I need help to save the code output in a text file
Because after each code run, all the previous words are deleted, but I want them to be stored in my file

Comment: @NikanNami [Writing a list to a file with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/writing-a-list-to-a-file-with-python)