# Writing a whole list AS SUCH to a text file in Python

Tags: python, list, writetofile

In python I don't want to write every single element into a file but a **whole list as such**. That means the text file should look like this for example:

```
["elem1", "elem2", "elem3"]
["elem1", "elem2", "elem3"]
["elem1", "elem2", "elem3"]
```

This is one examples to write each element from a list into a text file ([Writing a list to a file with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/writing-a-list-to-a-file-with-python/899176)). But I don't need this, as I said.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are three ways:

```
import json


l = ["elem1", "elem2", "elem3"]
print(str(l))
print(repr(l))
print(json.dumps(l))
```

Prints:

```
['elem1', 'elem2', 'elem3']
['elem1', 'elem2', 'elem3']
["elem1", "elem2", "elem3"]
```

You can, of course, direct your `print` statement to an output file.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated from original answer using `list.__str__()`**

You can achieve this by making use of `str()` as below.

```py
l = [1, 'this', 'is', 'a', 'list']

with open('example.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(l))
```

Contents of `example.txt`

```
[1, 'this', 'is', 'a', 'list']
```

Comment: `str(l)` is the Pythonic way - generally double-underscore (dunder) methods aren't called directly.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Spot on, much more pythonic. Feel a fool for jumping straight to a dunder! Thanks for pulling me up on that :) Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
with open('FILE.txt', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(myList.__str__())
```

Comment: `str(myList)` is the Pythonic way - generally double-underscore (dunder) methods aren't called directly.