# How to write a list to a file in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, file, logging

I have a list which looks like this:

```
dates_to_process = ['20201203', '20201201', '20201203']
```

This list changes every now and then but I try to write those dates into my logfile. I prefer it to be in chronoclical order if thats possible.

This is my code:

```
with open(log_location, 'a') as output:
    if output.tell() == 0:      
        output.write('Date last Run\n')
    output.write(dates_to_process + '\n')
```

This is my wished outcome if I open the log_file:

```
Date last Run
20201201
20201202
20201203
```

This is whay I get now when I run the code:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Comment: You can convert the list to a String like this `"\n".join(dates_to_process)`, before writing to the file. As it is, you are trying to concatenate `dates_to_process`, a list with a String `\n`.

Comment: does this answer your question? :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/writing-a-list-to-a-file-with-python

Comment: I feel that it's a pretty bad dupe as the question is about serialization/being able to get the original list back, whereas this is about writing a list to a file in a specific format.

Comment: Perhaps the dup target changed? The current link doesn't talk about serialization. Also, OP, the error you're getting is because `dates_to_process` is a list and `'\n'` is a string. You cant concatenate them. As suggested by the comments in the dup, try `thefile.write('\n'.join(thelist))` or loop over the list, writing each line individually.

Comment: the answer of @thefourtheye did the job actually but its not yet in chronoloical order is it?

Comment: @TangerCity If the data is going to be in this format, you can throw in a `sorted` after converting the list items to numbers with `int`.