# How to make antispam function discord.py?

Tags: variables, discord, discord.py, bots

I need antispam function on my discord server. Please help me. I tried this:

```
    import datetime
    import time

    time_window_milliseconds = 5000
    max_msg_per_window = 5
    author_msg_times = {}

    @client.event 
async def on_ready():
  print('logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing,name="stack overflow"))

@client.event 
async def on_message(message):
    global author_msg_counts
    
    ctx = await client.get_context(message)

      author_id = ctx.author.id
      # Get current epoch time in milliseconds
      curr_time = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp() * 1000
    
      # Make empty list for author id, if it does not exist
      if not author_msg_times.get(author_id, False):
          author_msg_times[author_id] = []
    
      # Append the time of this message to the users list of message times
      author_msg_times[author_id].append(curr_time)
    
      # Find the beginning of our time window.
      expr_time = curr_time - time_window_milliseconds
    
      # Find message times which occurred before the start of our window
      expired_msgs = [
          msg_time for msg_time in author_msg_times[author_id]
          if msg_time < expr_time
      ]
    
      # Remove all the expired messages times from our list
      for msg_time in expired_msgs:
          author_msg_times[author_id].remove(msg_time)
      # ^ note: we probably need to use a mutex here. Multiple threads
      # might be trying to update this at the same time. Not sure though.
    
      if len(author_msg_times[author_id]) > max_msg_per_window:
          await ctx.send("Stop Spamming")

ping()
client.run(os.getenv('token'))
```

And it doesn't seem to work when I type the same message over and over again. Can you guys please help me? I need the good antispam function which will work inside `on_message`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: "Implement this feature for me" or "how do I do this" is off-topic for this site. You have to make an honest attempt, and then ask a **specific question** about your algorithm or technique. If you have no idea where to start, you need to look up a tutorial or talk to a tutor. Stack Overflow is the wrong place to ask for general advice

Comment: thank you for help. I gonna do it myself then

Comment: help me please 1

Comment: I'm really confused. Why did you edit the whole question and changed it to another instead of making a new question?

Comment: because i need to wait for couple of days to ask new question. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best thing you can do is to make an event [on_member_join](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member%20join#discord.on_member_join), which will be called every time user joins. Then in this event, you can make a list instead of variables that will save user id, and their current currency.
`users_currency = ["user's id", "5$", "another user's id", "7$"]` and so on. Next, I would recommend saving it to a text file.

### Example code

```
global users_currency
users_currrency = []

@client.event
global users_currency
async def on_member_join(member): #on_member_join event
    user = str(member.id) #gets user's id and changes it to string
    users_currency.append(user) #adds user's id to your list
    users_currency.append("0") #sets the currency to 0
```

Now if someone will join their id will appear in list and change their currency to 0.

### How can you use assigned values in list

If you keep the code close to example higher then on `users_currrency[0]`, `users_currrency[2]`, [...]. You will get users' ids and on `users_currrency[1]`, `users_currrency[3]`, etc. You will get their currency. Then you can use `on_message` event or `@client.command` to make command that will [look for user's id in list](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/index) and [change next value](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/insert) - their currency.

### Saving it to a text file

You have to save it in a text file ([Writing a list to a file with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/writing-a-list-to-a-file-with-python/899176)) and then make a function that will run at the start of the bot and read everything from the file and assign it inside your list.
**Example code:**

```
with open("users_currency.txt") as f:
    rd=f.read()
    changed_to_a_list=rd.split()
    users_currency = changed_to_a_list
```

Comment: can you answer the new question too?