# How can I extract a portion of text from all lines of a file?

Tags: python, string

I have these sequences:

```
0,<|endoftext|>ERRDLLRFKH:GAGCGCCGCGACCTGTTACGATTTAAACAC<|endoftext|>
1,<|endoftext|>RRDLLRFKHG:CGCCGCGACCTGTTACGATTTAAACACGGC<|endoftext|>
2,<|endoftext|>RDLLRFKHGD:CGCGACCTGTTACGATTTAAACACGGCGAC<|endoftext|>
3,<|endoftext|>DLLRFKHGDS:GACCTGTTACGATTTAAACACGGCGACAGT<|endoftext|>
```

And I'd like to get only the aminoacid sequences, like this:

```
ERRDLLRFKH:
RRDLLRFKHG:
RDLLRFKHGD:
DLLRFKHGDS:
```

I have wrote this script so far:

```
with open("example_val.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith(""):
            line = line[:-1]
        print(line.split(":", 1))
```

Nevertheless, I got only the original sequences. Please give me some advice.

Comment: Use a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) with [lookbehind and lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups) assertions.

Comment: what should `line.startswith("")` do?

Comment: Oh, maybe I forgot to put "<", in order to identify the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex solution:

```py
import re

with open("example_val.txt") as f:
    re.findall("(?<=>)[a-zA-Z]*:", f.read())
```

Regex Explanation:

- `(?<=>)` : is a positive lookbehind which finds the > character before our match
- `[a-zA-Z]*:` : matches zero or more of characters present in a-z and A-Z with the colon at the end

Test in Regex101 : [regex101.com/r/qVGCYF/1](https://regex101.com/r/qVGCYF/1)

Comment: I got this error- TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: @arteagavskiy my bad, i changed it to f.read(). Should work now.

Comment: It would make your answer a lot better if you added an explanation of the regex.

Comment: Slight nitpick: A lookaround doesn't _match_ anything, it only asserts that the pattern exists before the thing it actually matches (i.e. `[a-zA-Z]*:`), which is why the result of `findall()` doesn't contain the `>`

Comment: Here's a regex101 link with your regex and OP's sample input. I find it helpful to include a link in my regex answers because it gives readers the opportunity to play with the regex. https://regex101.com/r/qVGCYF/1

Answer (score 1):

First, remember that storing something (e.g. in a list) is not the same as printing it -- if you need to use it later, you need to store all your amino acid sequences in a list when you parse your file. If you just want to display them and do nothing else, it's fine to print.

You have a bunch of ways to do this:

1. Use a regular expression with a lookbehind like [johann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73141204/843953)
2. Use a CSV reader to isolate just the second column of your comma-separated text file, and then slice the string, since you know the value you want starts at the 13th index and ends at the 23rd index

```
import csv

sequences = []  # Create an empty list to contain all sequences

with open("example_val.txt") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        element = row[1]      # Get the second element in the row
        seq = element[13:24]  # Slice the element
        sequences.append(seq) # Append to the list
        print(seq)            # Or print the current sequence
```

3. Find the index of `<|endoftext|>` in the string. Relative to this index `i`, you know that your sequence starts at the index `i + len('<|endoftext|>')`, and ends at `i + len('<|endoftext|>') + 10`

```
with open("example_val.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        i = line.find('<|endoftext|>')
        seq_start = i + len('<|endoftext|>')
        seq_end = seq_start + 10
        seq = line[seq_start:seq_end+1]  # Slice the line
        sequences.append(seq)            # Append to the list
        print(seq)                       # Or print the current sequence
```

Comment: Thank you for this useful information! I will use my sequences later, so yes, I will append them to a list.

Comment: How can I save the new sequences in a txt file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/writing-a-list-to-a-file-with-python-with-newlines @arteagavskiy