# How do I save two lists to file, and then load them back inte the correct order?

Tags: python, list, file, save, nested-lists

Lets say I have the two lists:

```
 test_names = [['timothy', 'tim'],["clara"],["jerry", "jer", "j-dog"],]   
 test_numbers = ['123','234', '345',]
```

I want to save them to a file, like this

123 ; timothy ; tim ;

234 ; clara ;

345 ; jerry ; jer ; j-dog ;

and then somehow return this file into the original lists above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing a list to a file with Python, with newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/writing-a-list-to-a-file-with-python-with-newlines). Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529815/saving-an-object-data-persistence); you can create `A=test_names, test_numbers`, and use pickle to write/read A.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this:

```
res = {}
for key in test_keys:
    for value in test_values:
        res[value] = key
        test_values.remove(value)
        break

with open("myfile.txt", 'w') as f: 
for key, value in res.items(): 
    f.write('%s;%s;\n' % (key, value))
```

Will result in something like this.

123;['timothy', 'tim'];

234;['clara'];

345;["jerry", "jer", "j-dog"];

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to contains two. It is better to focus on one, but don't worry, i'll anwser both

### TL; DR

#### Merge two list

```
list_A = ['abc', 'def', 'hij']   
list_B = ['123','234', '345']   
list_AB = []
for i in range(len(list_A)):
    list_AB.append([list_A[i], list_B[i]])
# output : [['abc', '123'], ['def', '234'], ['hij', '345']]
```

#### [Save to a file](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp)

```
f = open("output.txt", "w")
f.write(str(list_AB))
f.close()
```

### Explainations

In the TL;DR I provided a simple, general solution, but i'll give here a more detailled solution for your specific case

#### Merge two list

We loop trought all the elements of our lists :

```
for i in range(len(test_names)):
    combined_list = test_names[i]
    combined_list.insert(0, test_numbers[i])
    list_AB.append(combined_list)
```

*Note : `i` will go from `0` (included) to `len(list_A)` (excluded), but if the length of `list_B` is different from  `list_A`, we will have issues. This example should be improved if such cases are possibles.*

#### Save to file

First opening the file link

```
f = open("output.txt", 'w') # 'w' for write (remove old content), we can use 'a' to append at the end of old content
```

Don't forget to always close your file after editing it.

```
f.close() # Else other program can't access the file (appear as being in use by Python)
```

In-between, we will write all our content to our file. We will use a [forloop](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp) to iterate over all our elements inside `list_AB`

```
for element in list_AB:
    f.write(str(element) + ' ;\n')
# output :
# ['123', 'timothy', 'tim'] ;
# ['234', 'clara'] ;
# ['345', 'jerry', 'jer', 'j-dog'] ;
```

That is not exactly what we want. List are displayed as `["element1", "element2", ...]`, but we want a prettier output. We can use [.join](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp)() :

e.g. `'something'.join(list_AB)`

That will concat all element of the list, each separeted by a string (here the string "something")

```
for element in list_AB:
    f.write(' ; '.join(element) + ' ;\n')
# output :
# 123 ; timothy ; tim;
# 234 ; clara;
# 345 ; jerry ; jer ; j-dog;
```

Perfect :)

(don't forget to close your file)