# Put an append list into a table with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to put my append list into a table. I only can print one line of the list but not the others since the amount of numbers and words can varie from 1 to infinity

```
everthing = []
option = 0

while option < 5:
    Mainmenue = ["Main menue", "1. ADD AN ITEM", "4. GENERATE A REPORT"]

    for i in (Mainmenue):
        print(i)
    option = int(input("Option you want:"))

    if option == 1:
       item = (input("add an item:"))
       itemquantity = (input("Item quantity:"))
       everthing.append(item)
       everthing.append(itemquantity)
       print(everthing)
       
   
   

    elif option == 4:
      #Here is the question
      for thing in everthing:
       print(thing, sep='\t')  
      #Here is the question end

      Mainmenue = ["Main menue", "1. ADD AN ITEM","4. GENERATE A REPORT"]

      for i in (Mainmenue):
        print(i)
        option = float(input("Option you want:"))
```

When I run this code to give me a list it gives the table like this

```
Jam
40
Sprite
30
```

But I want it to be like this

```
Jam    40

Sprite 30
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close. However, you do have some redundant code.
I added a `5. QUIT` option to clarify the method to **exit** the program.

I tried to keep it within your specifications, however you may want to consider some **error checking** code to handle the issue if they **do not enter a number** when asked to select an option from the menu.

But here is a version of your program, keeping within the specifications:

```py
everthing = []
option = 0

while option < 5:
    Mainmenue = ["Main menue", 
                 "1. ADD AN ITEM", 
                 "4. GENERATE A REPORT",
                 "5. QUIT"]

    for i in (Mainmenue):
        print(i)
    option = int(input("Option you want:"))

    if option == 1:
        item = (input("add an item:"))
        itemquantity = (input("Item quantity:"))
        item_added = f"{item}\t{itemquantity}"
        everthing.append(item_added)
        print("Added:", item_added, "\n")
        
    elif option == 4:
        # Generate the report
        print("\n---------REPORT---------")
        for thing in everthing:
            print(thing)  
        print("------------------------\n")
```

**Here are the selections I made:**

- `1` : Option 1 (add an item)
- `Jam`
- `40`
- `1` : Option 1 (add an item)
- `Sprite`
- `30`
- `4` : Option 4 (generate report)
- `5` : Option 5 (quit)

**OUTPUT:**

```
Main menue
1. ADD AN ITEM
4. GENERATE A REPORT
5. QUIT
Added: Jam  40 

Main menue
1. ADD AN ITEM
4. GENERATE A REPORT
5. QUIT
Added: Sprite   30 

Main menue
1. ADD AN ITEM
4. GENERATE A REPORT
5. QUIT

---------REPORT---------
Jam     40
Sprite  30
------------------------

Main menue
1. ADD AN ITEM
4. GENERATE A REPORT
5. QUIT
```

While I noticed you used a tab to separate the `items` from the `qty`, you may want to use padding instead. This will ensure the quantities are more likely to line up with each other and are less dependent on the length of the item (ie. number of characters).

Here is what I would suggest in terms of padding.
I would change the code for `option 1` to the following:

```py
    if option == 1:
        padding = 21
        item = (input("add an item:")).ljust(padding)
        itemquantity = (input("Item quantity:"))
        item_added = f"{item}{itemquantity}"
        everthing.append(item_added)
        print("Added:", item_added, "\n")
```

You can see that I have included a `padding` variable, that allows up to `21` characters for the `item` variable using the `.ljust()` function.

The report ends up looking like this:

```
---------REPORT---------
Jam                  40
Sprite               30
------------------------
```

Comment: Would you know how to print the table also in .txt file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/writing-a-list-to-a-file-with-python-with-newlines

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` to get pair of `item` and `quantity` from `everything` list with index slicing:

```
#Here is the question
for item, quantity in zip(everything[0::2], everything[1::2]):
    print(f'{item} \t{quantity}')
#Here is the question end
```

Output:

```
Jam     40
Sprite  30
```